# Perl `dirname` prints dot instead of full path

Tags: perl

I am trying to implement a perl script and I need to get a directory of my executed file.

For example if my file that I'm executing is at `C:\Scripts\MyScript.pl` I would like to get `C:\Scripts`.

I tried `dirname` but it does not seem to do what i want. It just prints `.`

I understand that I need to use `dirname` and `abs_path` together, however `abs_path` seems buggy to me because it returns some UNIX looking directory and then concatenates it with the actual path which obviously is invalid path in the end.

Here is my proof of concept.

```
# The initial variable with file
say $0; # C:\Users\sed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\my-test-module\my-test-file

# This is just a current directory
say dirname($0); # .

# This looks like a bug to me, the shell is opened in C:/Users/sed so it is related
say abs_path($0); # /c/Users/sed/C:/Users/sed/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/my-test-module\my-test-file

# This is what I need, except I don't need that first UNIX looking part
say dirname(abs_path($0)); # /c/Users/sed/C:/Users/sed/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/my-test-module
```

Comment: It's weird that `$0` is a Windows path when you appear to be using a non-Windows build of `perl`. What's the first line of the `perl -v`?

Comment: Seems it's windows build. `This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for x86_64-msys-thread-multi`

Comment: No, it's a msys build, not Windows build. msys is a unix emulation environment. (A Windows build would start with `MSWin32-x64` instead of `x86_64-msys`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at:

```
perldoc File::Basename
```

shows why it may not be the best choice for what you need to do.
Please try File::Spec instead.

```
C:\Users\Ken> echo C:\Scripts\MyScript.pl | perl -MFile::Spec -lne "print $_; ($v,$d,$f)=File::Spec->splitpath($_); print $v.$d;"
C:\Scripts\MyScript.pl
C:\Scripts\
```

Type:

```
perldoc File::Spec
```

for more information. BTW, I tested with Strawberry perl v5.24.1

Comment: This has the same problem as doing it correctly (using `$FindBin::RealBin` or `dirname(abspath($0))`): It returns `.` for `C:\Scripts\MyScript.pl` on a unix machine. Changing `File::Spec` to `File::Spec::Win32` would do the trick, though (except it won't support symlinks like `$FindBin::RealBin` and `dirname(abspath($0))` do).

Answer (score 0):

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

say $RealBin;
```

Common use:

```
use lib $RealBin;
```

or

```
use lib "$RealBin/lib";
```

Comment: `say $RealBin;` gives back `/c/Users/sed/c/Users/sed/C:/Users/sed/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/my-test-module/my-test-file`

Comment: You passed a Windows path to a `perl` that runs in unix-emulation environment. Pass a native (msys) path to `perl` instead. (Apparently, the call to open a file accepts both Windows and native paths, but `abspath` (used by FindBin) thinks it's on a unix machine and performs accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

Using Strawberry Perl v5.26.1 I found that starting the script directly as in `MyScript.pl` gave a different result to starting it with Perl i.e. `perl MyScript.pl`. In the latter case I got the useless relative (dot) output.

The following worked for me in both cases:

```
use File::Basename;
use File::Spec;
my (undef, $this_script_folder, undef) = fileparse(File::Spec->rel2abs( __FILE__ ));
```